# Set entire GridView to be read-only

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, readonly

I know you can specify specific columns to only be `readonly` but does C# have a way of setting the entire grid to read only?

For example, I know this will set 1 column to read only,

```
dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].ReadOnly = true;
```

I tried this, but threw a compile-time error,

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
```

The error:

> Grid view does not contain a definition for Read Only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try iterate each column to set the entire GridView readonly

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    column.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: It must be done on a column by column basis?  Not possible to just set the entire grid?

Comment: are you using WebForm GridView or WinForm DataGridView? if WinForm then yes, you can set ReadOnly attribute.

Comment: No, you have to do it by column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the datagrid using a `foreach`/`for` loop and set each column's `.ReadOnly` property to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Since, by convention, it is the first column that contains the "edit" button of a GridView, you may simply hide this column to achieve ReadOnly.

```
foreach (GridView gv in this.Controls.All().OfType<GridView>())
{
    gv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```